# shell script to get file names from a path and store in variable in ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, gitlab

I am trying to find the file names in a path. Using following script, but getting issue when tries to put that name in a variable:

```
for file in "${PROJECT_DIR}/temp_namespaces"/*
do
    echo "${file##*/}"
    namespaces= "${file##*/}"
    echo "namespace = " > "${namespaces}"
done
```

it prints the file name from first echo, but after that both lines gives error:

```
namespaces= "${file##*/}"                ----   command not found
echo "namespace = " > "${namespaces}"    ----  No such file or directory
```

I am using linux available on **amazon/aws-cli** base image to run the above script.

I need to get the file names from a path and store them in a variable that will be used later in script to run few more commands.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Strangely I found that script got fixed when removed space and quotes from following line:

```
namespaces= "${file##*/}"
```

and changed it as:

```
namespaces=${file##*/}
```

removing one space and quotes, that's all.

Comment: Nothing strange. Spaces around `=` [do matter](https://superuser.com/a/1669093/432690); and it's [one of few cases where double-quotes don't matter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/108618). The space was the culprit, the quotes could stay.