# Why does Zsh complain of my variable assignment as "command not found"?

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, macos-bigsur

When I try to write a Zsh script on macOS Big Sur, Version 11.5.1, I noticed that it keeps failing to recognize my variables as variables.

Instead, Zsh treats them as UNIX-like commands.

[Screenshot of the problem on the Terminal Application - variable assignment problem for Zsh shell scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNkYQ.jpg)

In the screenshot linked above, I did the following on the *Terminal* application.

- Showed the contents of the simple Zsh shell script.
- Used the "ls -l" UNIX-like command to indicate its file permissions, and show that it is an executable Zsh shell script.
- Executed the Zsh shell script, which shows that the Zsh script interpreter complains of how my variable name is a "command not found".

The source code for my Zsh shell script is provided as follows:

```
#!/bin/zsh

unix_cmd = "ls -al"
```

Can you please kindly let me know what am I missing, and what did I do wrong?

I just want to assign values to variables in my Zsh shell scripts.

Thank you so much, and have a great day! Ciao!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax to assign a value to a variable is `foo=bar`, *not* `foo = bar`. Whitespaces matter. The latter syntax is a command `foo` with arguments `=` and `bar`.

Few examples of how `=` is interpreted:

| code | meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `foo=bar` | proper assignment; now the value of `foo` is `bar` |
| `foo = bar` | command `foo` with arguments `=` and `bar` |
| `foo =bar` | command `foo` with one argument `=bar` |
| `foo= bar` | command `bar` with `foo` in its environment; the value of `foo` is empty |
| `foo=1 bar` | command `bar` with `foo` in its environment; the value of `foo` is `1` |
| `foo='1 bar'` | proper assignment; now the value of `foo` is `1 bar` |
| `foo=' bar'` | proper assignment; now the value of `foo` is `bar` (note the leading space) |
| `foo=\ bar` | proper assignment; now the value of `foo` is `bar` (note the leading space) |
| `foo-x=bar` | command `foo-x=bar` (because `foo-x` is not a valid name for a shell variable) |

This is not specific to Zsh. The POSIX shell (`sh`) and POSIX-compliant shells behave this way. Zsh (while not being POSIX-compliant in general) also follows.

Comment: My upvote can only be recorded but not cast, since my reputation score is low for the "Super User" site of Stack Exchange.

That said, thank you so much! It makes a lot of sense now.